# Ionic Lifecycle Un-/Subscribe Firebase Databasestreams (using async pipe)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

I am using Ionic 5 with Firebase Realtime Database and Firestore (angularfire) and Angular Routing. On most pages I am streaming databasecontent.
Because of the Ionic-lifecycle the pages are not destroyed when leaving the view.
As I would do in Angular, I declare my Observables in ngOnInit.

```
public data$: Observable<Data[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
      this.data$ = this.dataService.retrieveData();
```

In my template I am using async pipe.

The async pipe would automaticly unsubscribe when the component is destroyed. But because of the Ionic lifecycle this does not happen, when leaving the view.

**Question 1:**
Is it good practice to keep the databasestreaming open when leaving views (and only unsubscribe when onNgDestroy is called)?

**Question 2:**
If it is preferred to use the lifecycle hooks (i.e. ionViewWillEnter, ionViewWillLeave) it would not be possible to use the async pipe, so I have to do subscribing an unsubscribing on my own. Not using async pipes sounds unreasonable. In which usecases does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1**: I think it is an individuel consideration. But in moste cases it does nor make sense to keep the streams open, when leaving a page.

**Question 2**: Seeing Q1, you should use ionViewWillEnter to subscribe and ionViewWillLeave to unsubscribe. In that cases async pipes does not make sense.

In the end I am not happy about the own ionic lifecycle. But that is the way it is.